# PyQt doesn't switch the screen

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I've written a GUI program which do a lot of calculation in the back, at the same time, display a progress bar. After it was done, a new screen will show the result.

Then I want to make another interface before the calculation to let the user select if they want to use the last calculation result, thus skipping the calculation.

I made a screen with a button which connected to the calculation, and a combo box to select last calculation result file.

However, when I clicked the button, it did nothing. And after around 10 secs( the duration for the calculation ), the result screen pop open. Thus, it skipped the progress bar screen. Why?

This it part of the original program:

```
import sys
import configparser
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time
import subprocess
from datetime import *

from log_tracker import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Task_Checker(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Task_Checker, self).__init__()

        config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read('profile.cfg')
        self.log_path = config.get('Config', 'log_path')
        self.log_prefix = config.get('Config', 'log_prefix')
        self.log_suffix = config.get('Config', 'log_suffix')

        self.initUI()

    def check_production(self):
        self.log_tracker = Log_Tracker(self)
        self.log_tracker.tick.connect(self.pbar.setValue)
        self.log_tracker.parseConfig()
        self.log_tracker.connectDb()
        self.log_tracker.trackLog()



    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1400, 768)
        self.center()

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Checking Production Programs')

        self.wait_message = QLabel('Checking Production Programs')
        self.wait_message.setAlignment(Qt.Alignment(Qt.AlignHCenter))
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(100)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.wait_message)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        tmpWidget2 = QWidget()
        tmpWidget2.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(tmpWidget2)
        self.show()

        self.check_production()

        self.pbar.hide()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Processing Information')

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()        
        mua_table = self.processInfo('MUA')
        bps_table = self.processInfo('BPS')
        obdua_table = self.processInfo('OBDUA')
        sua_table = self.processInfo('SUA')
        ngr_ftp_table = self.processInfo('NGR_FTP')
        bpspdfbill_table = self.processInfo('BpsPdfBill')
        disk_space_table = self.processInfo('Disk_Space')        
        self.tabs.addTab(mua_table, 'MUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(bps_table, 'BPS')
        self.tabs.addTab(obdua_table, 'ODBUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(sua_table, 'SUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(ngr_ftp_table, 'NGR_FTP')
        self.tabs.addTab(bpspdfbill_table, 'BpsPdfBill')
        self.tabs.addTab(disk_space_table, 'Disk_Space')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setWindowTitle('Task Checker')    
        self.show()

    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())



    def processInfo(self, project_name):
        ...the processing...
```

In order to add a new screen before the progress bar ( originally it loads the calculation right away ), I made a fews changes to initUI() and move the calculation part to a new sub routine checkProd(), then connect it with a button:

```
import sys
import configparser
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time
import subprocess
from datetime import *

from log_tracker import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Task_Checker(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Task_Checker, self).__init__()

        config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read('profile.cfg')
        self.log_path = config.get('Config', 'log_path')
        self.log_prefix = config.get('Config', 'log_prefix')
        self.log_suffix = config.get('Config', 'log_suffix')

        self.initUI()

    def check_production(self):
        self.log_tracker = Log_Tracker(self)
        self.log_tracker.tick.connect(self.pbar.setValue)
        self.log_tracker.parseConfig()
        self.log_tracker.connectDb()
        self.log_tracker.trackLog()



    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1400, 768)
        self.center()

        btn_check = QPushButton('Check Lastest Status', self)
        btn_check.setToolTip('Click this if you want to check the lastest status in production')

        combo = QComboBox()
        dirlist = os.listdir(self.log_path)
        for f in dirlist:
            combo.addItem(f)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(btn_check, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.checkProd)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn_check)
        hbox.addWidget(combo)
        tmpWidget = QWidget()
        tmpWidget.setLayout(hbox)        
        self.setCentralWidget(tmpWidget)
        self.show()

    def checkProd(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Checking Production Programs')

        self.wait_message = QLabel('Checking Production Programs')
        self.wait_message.setAlignment(Qt.Alignment(Qt.AlignHCenter))
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(100)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.wait_message)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        tmpWidget2 = QWidget()
        tmpWidget2.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(tmpWidget2)
        self.show()


        self.check_production()

        self.pbar.hide()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Processing Information')

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()        
        mua_table = self.processInfo('MUA')
        bps_table = self.processInfo('BPS')
        obdua_table = self.processInfo('OBDUA')
        sua_table = self.processInfo('SUA')
        ngr_ftp_table = self.processInfo('NGR_FTP')
        bpspdfbill_table = self.processInfo('BpsPdfBill')
        disk_space_table = self.processInfo('Disk_Space')        
        self.tabs.addTab(mua_table, 'MUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(bps_table, 'BPS')
        self.tabs.addTab(obdua_table, 'ODBUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(sua_table, 'SUA')
        self.tabs.addTab(ngr_ftp_table, 'NGR_FTP')
        self.tabs.addTab(bpspdfbill_table, 'BpsPdfBill')
        self.tabs.addTab(disk_space_table, 'Disk_Space')

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setWindowTitle('Task Checker')    
        self.show()


    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())



    def processInfo(self, project_name):
        ...the processing...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of unnecessary code to read, but what I have managed to parse out of it, is that you are doing heavy calculations in the main thread, while expecting another widget in the main thread to also maintain responsiveness.

This is a common pitfall when working with PyQt4 (and probably most GUI frameworks that use a main thread event loop). The issue is that when you start your app, the main event loop constantly polls for new events to process from your GUI. Its expecting that every operation should either take a very short time to complete, or, periodically relinquish control back to the eventloop. Right now, your calculation is hogging up all the availability of the main thread, and anything that your progress window is trying to do is just backing up into a queue waiting for a chance for the event loop to pick it up.

The simple answer to this is: Do any heavy calculations in a separate [QThread](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html), and communicate back to your main thread via signals. This will require a little bit of retooling on you part. You should not put anything heavy into an init of any class. But you have managed to address this in your second example by attaching the computation to a button. Good start. The button should actually start the calc in another thread, thus not blocking up the main thread.

#### [Qt4.7 Threading Basics](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/thread-basics.html)

> **GUI Thread and Worker Thread**
>   As mentioned, each program has one thread
>   when it is started. This thread is called the "main thread" (also
>   known as the "GUI thread" in Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in
>   this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example
>   QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads. A secondary thread is
>   commonly referred to as a "worker thread" because it is used to
>   offload processing work from the main thread.
>   ...
>   **Using Threads**
>   There are basically two use cases for threads:
>   1. Make
>   processing faster by making use of multicore processors.
>   2. Keep the GUI
>   thread or other time critical threads responsive by offloading long
>   lasting processing or blocking calls to other threads.

As a quick fix if you just want to see some results, you can periodically call [`QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) from your calculation method. This will every so often allow the event loop to flush out pending operations. Doing so will let something like your progress widget actually function. Essentially what you are doing is manually "pumping" the event loop. This isn't the best approach though. Usually its reserved for lighter weight one off stuff. If you want the best performance, move it to a thread.